# Play / Scala / sbt: docker:publichLocal with specific .conf file

Tags: playframework, sbt-native-packager, sbt-docker

I try in vain to deploy and run my play app from sbt-native-packager with the command "sbt docker:publishLocal" with a **specific .conf-file** on Docker.

The command as such works, the image is created, containers of it are executable. The created image contains all .conf files.  - but it does not take the .conf file it is supposed to.

In the **build.sbt** I tried the following:

```
maintainer := "XYZ"
dockerExposedPorts in Docker := Seq(9000)
javaOptions in Docker += "-Dconfig.resource=application.test.conf"
```

The following command is also unsuccessful: `"sbt -Dconfig.resource=application.test.conf docker:publishLocal"`.

Unfortunately I have no more ideas to solve the problem and would be grateful for any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You got this almost right. The `javaOptions` can only be set in the `Universal` scope. See the [customize java app section](https://praxistipps.chip.de/windows-10-dns-server-aendern-so-gehts_47055).

This documentation section also contains other possibilities to configure your app.

Hope that helps,
Muki